# Is self-adjoint the same as hyper-maximal symmetric?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I'm reading von Neumanns 1931 book on Quantum Mechanics. Here he presents spectral theory for unbounded operators and quite a bit of the notation and naming has changed in the mean time.

Specifically for him a symmetric operator (for all $x,y\in D(A)$ $\langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,Ay\rangle$) is called hermitian and an symmetric operator is called maximal if it admits no proper symmetric extensions.

He characterises maximality via the Cayley Transform, an operator $A$ is maximal iff the Cayley Transform $U(A)$ has image or domain the entire Hilbert space $H$. An operator is defined to be hyper-maximal if the Cayley Transform is unitary, ie has both image and domain all of $H$. He shows that the hyper-maximal symmetric operators are precisely those that admit a spectral decomposition.

For example it is clear that self-adjoint implies maximal: If $A=A^*$ and $B$ is symmetric so that $B\lvert_{D(A)}=A$, if $y\in D(B)$ then for every $x\in D(A)$ you've got:
$$|\langle Ax,y\rangle| =| \langle x,By\rangle| ≤\|x\|\,\|By\|$$
it follows $y\in D(A^*)=D(A)$ and $A^*y = By$.

My questions:

> What is the modern terminology for maximal?

And

> Is hyper-maximal the same as self-adjoint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual term for "maximal" is now "maximally symmetric," meaning that $A$ is symmetric and there are no proper symmetric extensions. von Neumann's work gives the decomposition
$$
              \mathcal{D}(A^*)=\mathcal{D}(A)\oplus\mathcal{N}(A^*-iI)\oplus\mathcal{N}(A^*+iI),
$$
which is orthogonal with respect to the following graph inner product
$$
         \langle x,y\rangle_{A^*}=\langle x,y\rangle_H+\langle A^*x,A^*y\rangle_H.
$$
If neither of the deficiency spaces $\mathcal{N}(A^*\pm iI)$ is $\{0\}$, then you can always extend $A$ in such a way that the extension remains symmetric. (You can write down such an extension.) So maximally symmetric operators $A$ have either $\mathcal{N}(A^*-iI)=\{0\}$ or $\mathcal{N}(A^*+iI)=\{0\}$. These are maximal, as you have described them. If both are $\{0\}$, then $A^*=A$ because they have the same domain and $A^*$ extends $A$, and this is what you have referred to as hyper-maximal.

This can be recast without too much trouble in terms of the Cayley transform.

Comment: Do you also know what Neumann meant when he said the maximal but non-hypermaximal operators all arise from two normal forms and can therefore be considered anomalies? (German original: "Derartige Operatoren existieren in der Tat, und sie entstehen alle aus zwei einfachen Normalformen, so dass man sie, den maximal Operatoren mit lösbarem Eigenerproblem gegenübergestellt, als Ausnahmefälle ansehen kann")

Comment: Does he simply mean the two cases of but not the other deficiency space vanishing? Though it's still not clear why that would be more of a special case than both or none vanishing

Comment: @Bananach : Based on what you wrote, maximal would be where one, but not both, of $\mathcal{N}(A^*\pm i)$ is $\{0\}$, and hypermaximal would be where both are $\{0\}$, which is the case for a self-adjoint operator.

Comment: @Bananach : von Neumann is a different person than Neumman, the person after whom boundary conditions are named. von Neumann invented the CPU, and worked on atomic bombs.

Comment: I know that, forgive me dropping the von. Thanks for the clarification about hypermaximality