# How is a self-adjoint operator (hyper-)maximal?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

I may be missing something obvious, but is self-adjoint operator in a complex separable Hilbert space (hyper-)maximal?

**Lemma**: Let $A:D(A) \subsetneq\mathcal H\rightarrow \mathcal H$ self-adjoint, i.e. $A=A^{*}$. Let $B$ an extension of $A$, i.e. $D(A)\subsetneq D(B)$ and $A\phi = B\phi, \forall \phi\in D(A)$. Then $A=B$.

**Proof**:??

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227587/is-self-adjoint-the-same-as-hyper-maximal-symmetric

Answer (score 1):

It follows from $\mathscr R(A\pm i)= \mathscr H$, see [Theorem 3.79](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Evpaulsen/FAQIChapter3.pdf#page=29). Corollory 2 [here](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Efeldman/m511/cayley.pdf) for a proof.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually always extend any unbounded operator, including self-adjoint ones, with the following procedure: if $A : D(A) \subset X \to Y$ is any linear operator with $D(A) \neq X$, then, by taking $x_0 \in X \setminus D(A)$ and $y_0 \in Y$, you can construct the linear operator which follows:
$$B_{(x_0,y_0)} : x + \alpha x_0 \in D(A) + \mathbb{K}x_0 \mapsto A(u) + \alpha y_0$$

and you can probably use Zorn's lemma to define infinitely many everywhere-defined extensions by continuing inductively the process with further extensions, but I haven't dabbled much in these types of arguments.

Now that this claim is answered by the negative, time for a positive result.

Keith's answer is wrong currently but works for symmetric extensions, as a self-adjoint operator is maximally symmetric, I'm guessing they did not see that there was no symmetry condition on the extensions for this question. Their way and the post they linked in their above comment are a little convoluted (for what's needed here), although it's better if you want to understand more about what's happening. You can see the maximal symmetry much faster and in a much simpler fashion (I believe that's what's done in Rudin's FA):

Recall that a densely defined operator $A$ is symmetric iff $A \subset A^*$, by definition of the adjoint pretty much, and that $A \subset B$ implies $B^* \subset A^*$, again almost by definition.
Let $H$ be a self-adjoint operator, and let $S$ be a symmetric extension of $H$. We have: $$S \subset S^* \subset H^* = H \subset S$$ hence all the inclusions are equalities, and we get $S = H$.

(Note that for non-symmetric but closable extensions $S$ you still get that $S^* \subset H \subset S \subset  \bar{S} = S^{**}$ and thus that $S^*$ is symmetric, which means that, since there is a self-adjoint of $S^*$ (which is $H$), the deficiency indexes [indices?] of $S^*$ are equal, hence: $\dim \ker (\bar{S} - i \mathrm{Id}) = \dim \ker (\bar{S} + i \mathrm{Id})$. That's something I suppose. But I digress...)